# Socket.io client specific variable

Tags: node.js, session, variables, scope, socket.io

How do I store session specific info in Socket.io?

```
var client={}; //is this static across all sockets (or connected clients) that are connected? 
io.on('connection', function(socket){

  client.connectiontime=Date.now();
});


//on another io.on('connection') for the same connected client
io.on('connection', function(socket){
 store(client.connectiontime);
}
```

How do I use the client variable only for the operations related to the currently connected client if it is considered static?

Answer (score 2):

First, each socket is given a name that can be used to refer to it, but that changes each time the same client connects so this would not be useful if it is supposed to remain after the client leaves. If your goal is to store the connection time somewhere (a database?) then you would have to get a unique identifier from the client that could be used to find them again similar to a login. You would then pass the date object into the function that handles storing that time.

You should note though, that 'connection' is only called the first time the socket connects. A connection is not the event you normally would be using for when a client does something unless they disconnects between each access of the server program.

If you are sure you want to just use the Client object, you would likely have to create a client array and use the socket id as a key to access the object later. You would then have something like

array[socket.id].connectiontime = Date.now()

```
var client={}; //is this static across all sockets (or connected clients) that are connected? 
var clients = [];
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  clients[] = {
                id : socket.id
                connectiontime : Date.now()
  }
});


//on another io.on('connection') for the same connected client
io.on('connection', function(socket){
// Here you would search for the object by socket.id and then store
 store(client.connectiontime);
}
```

Comment: But is there a variable that can be used only for this particular clients session?

Comment: On 'connection' a socket.id is generated and that is the id that the program uses the recognize which socket it is communicating with. So in the code I provided, the id: socket.id part is using that unique identifier. It will not tell you the person, because it changes if they disconnect and reconnect, but it will be the identifier specifically for that user's session while connected to the server code

Comment: So I need to manage this manually? I thought socket io would provide some way to store values meant only for each clients session and save me from the work of maintaining clients and their sessions

Comment: You may be able to add a property to the socket object the same way you would any other object. I have not tried this as of yet though, so I do not know how well it works.